# обращение beaver__eye::before через js

Tags: javascript, css

Как обратится к такому свойству через js?

```
.beaver__eye::before {

  transform:scale(1);

}
```

// пытаюсь так но выдаёт ошибку

```
 document.getElementsByClassName('beaver__eye::before')[0].style.transform = 'scale(3)';
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нельзя обратиться к псевдоэлементу через js

Comment: спасибо посмотрите пожалуйста этот вопрос https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/999823/border-size-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%8f%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b9-%d1%8d%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82-%d0%b8%d0%b7-js