# --border-size: как поменять такой элемент(css переменную) из js?

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, svg-animation

```
#beavershadow1321232 {
  --border-size: 2px;

}
```

так не работает

```
 document.getElementById("beavershadow1321232").style.--border-size = "20px";
```

Comment: Извините, но что такое "border-size", что вы хотите изменить?)

Comment: Зачем вы сняли галочку правильный ответ с правильного ответа?

Comment: Новый ответ,мне понравился больше чем старый.

Comment: @StrangerintheQ Разве ответ от Александра неправильный? И к слову, ответ с галочкой называется: _принятый ответ_.

Comment: @0xdb вопрос был про то как установить переменную css, а ответ Александра про что то другое

Comment: @Ivan912 про что был Ваш вопрос?

Comment: @StrangerintheQ Раз так, посмотрю внимательней. Спасибо!

Comment: @Stranger in the Q Очень странно выглядят твои возмущения. Правило одно - **окончательное решение,  какой выбрать ответ, исключительное право автора вопроса**. Если позже появится **новый ответ**, который ещё больше понравится OP, то я не буду возражать на снятие галочки. Повторюсь - только автору решать, какой ему ответ больше подходит.

Comment: @Alexandr_TT вопрос был про css переменные и как установить их из js, причем тут svg? это все таки вопросы и ответы по проблемам, а теперь первым ответом красуется бобёр, а до ответа на вопрос надо скроллить вниз.

Comment: @Stranger in the Q что ты от меня хочешь? Чтобы я снял галочку со своего ответа :-) Так на это есть права только у автора вопроса. А он однозначно ответил, что выбранный ответ ему подходит больше.

Comment: @Stranger in the Q Тебя интересует почему я выбрал анимацию глаз бобра? Посмотри внимательно, какое имя у элемента `beavershadow` и он должен увеличиваться с 2px до 20px/ ясное дело, что автор хотел получить пример анимации глаз бобра, что я и сделал. Вот ранее у автора был вопрос [по увеличению глаз бобра](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/999817/%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%89%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-beaver-eyebefore-%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b7-js?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: Мне кажется, что тут нужно менять название и описание вопроса.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### SVG + JS

Из вопроса и ответов я понял, что главная задача - сделать анимацию изменения контуров объекта.

1. Пример анимированного смайла, где происходит моргание левым глазом после клика.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Для анимирования используется изменение радиуса эллипса `ry`

Неравномерность моргания обеспечивают атрибуты:

```
 keyTimes=" 0;0.25;0.5;0.75;1"
     values="10;0;5;0;10"
```

```html
<svg  id="svg1" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
    
     width="100" height="100" viewBox="0 0 100 100" >  
<rect x="10" y="0" rx="15" width="85" height="100" fill="gold" />
 
<g id="gr1"> 
<ellipse cx="35" cy="35" ry="10" rx="12" fill="black" >
 </ellipse>
<ellipse cx="70" cy="35" ry="10" rx="12" fill="black" >
    <animate
  attributeName="ry"
  dur="1s"
  begin="svg1.click"
  keyTimes=" 0;0.25;0.5;0.75;1"
  values="10;0;5;0;10"
  repeatCount="1" /> 
</ellipse>
</g>
 
<circle cx="52.5" cy="50" r="30" fill="none" stroke="black" stroke-dashoffset="-6" stroke-dasharray="80 108.49" />
</svg>
```

2. Пример оживления картинки `*.jpg` c применением анимации атрибута `d` path 
   (моргание глазом)

Техника реализации в этом примере немного сложнее, поэтому приведу некоторые объяснения:

- Выбираем любую понравившуюся картинку:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Допустим нужно изобразить моргание левого глаза после клика по картинке

- Загружаем в векторный редактор изображение бобра и инструментом <kbd>рисовать
  кривые Безье</kbd> наносим узловые точки исходного положения века

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

- Сохраняем файл в формате `*.svg` и копируем  path исходного состояния
  века
- перетаскиваем нижние узловые точки в положение закрытого века и
  рычагами управления узловых точек (красные стрелки) придаем нужную форму кривой

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

- снова сохраняем файл и копируем патч закрытого века

### Анимация закрывания века

Соль анимации заключается в изменении path открытого века на path закрытого века и обратно к открытому веку.
Значения патчей записываются в атрибут `values` через точку с запятой.

Главное условие плавности анимации,  без рывков, это - одинаковое количество узловых точек во всех патчах. Это достигается техникой, которая описана выше.

```js
var btn = document.getElementById('btn1');
var an_eye = document.getElementById('an_eye');
btn.onclick = function () {
an_eye.beginElement();
}
```

```css
path {
fill:#7A3609;
stroke:#000;
stroke-width:4;
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
<button type="button" id="btn1"> Бобёр моргай </button>

</div>
<svg id="svg1" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
       width="800" height="800" viewBox="0 0 800 800" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet">  

<image xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/kPh1N.jpg" width="100%" height="100%" />
 <path  d="m308 173c-9 5 3-20 10-28 6-6 15-11 23-10 11 0 22 6 29 14 7 8 16 37 7 31-16-10-22-14-34-16-12-1-20 0-34 8z" id="path12">
  <animate id="an_eye"
    attributeName="d"
 dur="0.8s"
 begin="indefinite"
 values="
  m308 173c-9 5 3-20 10-28 6-6 15-11 23-10 11 0 22 6 29 14 7 8 16 37 7 31-16-10-22-14-34-16-12-1-20 0-34 8z;
  m308 173c-4-9 3-20 10-28 6-6 15-11 23-10 11 0 22 6 29 14 7 8 13 22 7 31-9 14-21 25-34 24-15-1-25-9-34-31z;
  m308 173c-9 5 3-20 10-28 6-6 15-11 23-10 11 0 22 6 29 14 7 8 16 37 7 31-16-10-22-14-34-16-12-1-20 0-34 8z"
  repeatCount="2" />
 </path>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 5):

```js
document.body.addEventListener('click', () => {
  document.querySelector(".beaver__eye").style.setProperty('--beav-border', 20 + 'px')
})
```

```css
html {
  --beav-border: 5px;
}

.beaver__eye {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
  color: red;
  border-radius: var(--beav-border)
}
```

```html
<div class='beaver__eye'></div>
```

Не встречал свойства `border-size`, поэтому показал на примере `border-radius`. Кликните по красному блоку, чтобы применить действие.

Answer (score 0):

На вашем месте я бы воспользовался библиотекой jQuery,так было бы проще все реализовать

Если же вы хотите сделать это исключительно через JS могу посоветовать несколько вариантов

Используя css,а после получить его через toggle(className) 
Или же

```
       function changeStyleDiv(){
          document.getElementById('targetDiv').style.border = '20px solid red';
       }
```

Comment: По-моему ты вопрос не читал...

Comment: Не понимаю цель данного вопроса,что такое --border-size ?Тогда ответ был бы другим

Comment: Это css-переменные: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties

Comment: @Qwertiy  css-переменные это относится к sass, scss и т.д. ?

Comment: @Leks, нет, к css. Я же даже ссылку дал. И вообще, в соседнем ответе есть пример.

Comment: @Qwertiy как понял идея взята из препроцессоров  и в css проходит обкатку как экспериментальная технология ? и как модно посмотреть ее поддержку в https://caniuse.com/ ?

Comment: @Leks, оно работает не как в препрцессорах. Поддержка уже вполне приличная: https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-variables